# Rails: understanding custom form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @star do |f|%>
  <%= star_radio(f, true)%>
<% end %>
```

stars_helper.rb

```
module StarHelper
  def star_radio(form, status)
    form.label "star_#{status}", class: 'radio-inline' do
       form.radio_button(:star, status) + i18n_star(status)
    end
  end

  def i18n_star (status)
    I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.star.is_sun.#{status}")
  end
end
```

I saw a piece of code like above.
I am not familiar with custom form helper.
Could you let me know why we can use `form.radio_button(:star, status) + i18n_star(status)` inside a block and why we can use '+' to add text on radio buttons.
I will be appreciated if you could tell me where I can go to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.radio_button` helper returns a string and `I18n.t` too returns a string. So, you can concatenate them.

**More details how form tag is generated**

This is a code of `radio_button`:

https://github.com/casunlight/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb

```
def radio_button(object_name, method, tag_value, options = {})
  Tags::RadioButton.new(object_name, method, self, tag_value, options).render
end
```

Look at implementation of render method

https://github.com/casunlight/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/radio_button.rb#L20

```
def render
  options = @options.stringify_keys
  options["type"]     = "radio"
  options["value"]    = @tag_value
  options["checked"] = "checked" if input_checked?(object, options)
  add_default_name_and_id_for_value(@tag_value, options)
  tag("input", options)
end
```

Tag helper generate html tag and return his as html safed string:

https://github.com/casunlight/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L67

```
def tag(name, options = nil, open = false, escape = true)
  "<#{name}#{tag_options(options, escape) if options}#{open ? ">" : " />"}".html_safe
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As a beginner, most of time I user form helper like `<%= f.label :attr %> <%= f.radio_button :attr %>` , but here used block like this `form.label "star_#{status}", class: 'radio-inline' do
       form.radio_button(:star, status) + i18n_star(status)
end`. I am confused by this

Comment: Yes, you can pass block of code to form's label method. Last parameter `&block` in method definition `def label(object_name, method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)`    https://github.com/casunlight/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L750